# How does one get the job ID of an interactive job from an environment variable when using condor?

Tags: hpc, condor

I usually got the job id with:

```
MY_CONDOR_JOB_ID
```

but I don't see it set if it's an interactive job. Is there a way to set it? When I am given the resources I see that there is a job id for my job. Is there a way to get it?

Here is what it should be

```
Submitting job(s).
1 job(s) submitted to cluster 4869.
Waiting for job to start...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTCondor proper doesn't set MY_CONDOR_JOB_ID, so either your submit file or your administrator has set this up.

If your submit file contains

```
environment = CONDOR_JOB_ID=$(Cluster)
```

Then HTCondor will insert the job cluster id into the environment variable CONDOR_JOB_ID.  To get this into a condor_submit -i, you'll need to pass the name of this submit file to condor_submit.  So, try putting that into a submit file, maybe named env.sub, and run

```
condor_submit -i env.sub
```

Or, if you already have a submit file which sets this, pass the name of that submit file to condor_submit -i

Comment: will `environment = CONDOR_JOB_ID=$(Cluster)` only pass a single env variable or will it pass that PLUS all the other envs that should be already there?

Comment: This will add the environment variable to any others that are set by other means